# If relation $R$ is not well-founded is then at least one of these conditions satisfied?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $R$ be a relation (or a class of ordered pairs) and call $R$ well-founded if
any nonempty set $B$ contains an element $b\in B$ such that $B\cap\left\{ a\mid aRb\right\} =\emptyset$.
Here $aRb$ stands for $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle \in R$.

It is clear to me (and not quite difficult to prove) that $R$ is **not**
well-founded if at least one of the following conditions is satisfied:

- A function $f$ exists having a natural number $n>0$ as domain
  with $f\left(i+1\right)Rf\left(i\right)$ for each $i<n-1$ and $f\left(0\right)Rf\left(n-1\right)$.
- A function $f$ exists having $\omega$ (the set of natural numbers)
  as domain with $f\left(i+1\right)Rf\left(i\right)$ for each $i\in\omega$.

> My question: Is the converse of this valid? I.e. if $R$ is not well-founded can we conclude that at least on these conditions is satisfied?

My intuition says 'yes' but if it is right then I would like to see
a rigorous proof that is punctual when it comes to "choosing".

Comment: Do you assume the axiom of choice? (Note that the second condition includes the first, simply by "repeating" the finite cycle.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila If it cannot be proven without the AC then I have no choice: I accept the AC. ;)

Comment: @Vera: It actually needs only the axiom of dependent choice, if that makes you any happier. :-)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you, then I 'choose' for that :). I am not familiar with it yet, but will do some googling.